# How to display dynamic parameters in an HTML Email using javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, aem

I retrieving the Off time of a page and returning `offtimeQuery.toString()` and retrieving the page title `String resultPageTitle = resultPage.getTitle();` using java.

I am sending an email to the content authors of all the pages which have reached off time. How do i display this off time and page name in my HTML email using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

It is near impossible to make an email with JS in it.  If you do manage, then half of the email clients will tear it apart to protect to client-side computer.

Instead, I assume that you are using a Linux box for hosting, you could do two things that would work.  Use a bash file or equivalent to dynamically create the page and then fire it off  at given times, followed immediately by an email that serves the HTML of that page.  That is pretty easy.

The other way would be to use a JS file to do the same.  This could work through either time-based(HARD) or by you accessing the page through a browser when you wanted it to go.  Again, dynamically create the page with JS and then use the system to send the HTML of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use javascript. Almost all HTML email clients will not run any Javascript, because it is a huge security hole.

Instead put the relevant data into the body of the email as you construct it in your Java code. Presumably you have, in your Java code, those bits of data, and you have the HTML content you're sending as an email. Insert the data there, at most basic using `String.format(template, data, ...)`. But if you are going to do anything other than trivial replacement, use a proper HTML templating system.

Don't try to include any javascript with a HTML email. You may be able to find an email client where it works, but won't for most of your clients.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript gets stripped from email messages due to concerns with security. You could force a redirect and perform phishing attacks, and steal other nasty info such as cookies from the domain that the email was sent to if Dynamic emails were made possible with javascript.

If you are really interested in displaying dynamic content, and don't care how, think about creating a server script which returns an image. You could pass a static identifier to the script, and it could return a dynamic result.

See my project in php at https://github.com/TabLand/EmailTracker which generates dynamic images. Only the time string is dynamic. I'd show you the demonstration, but would end up logging your useragent and IP address!